# How to filter data by datetime format parameter in ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get lists of data based on the DateTime parameter. But it's not working as I get the error-  AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. But when I am trying to retrieve data based on an int ID parameter it's working.Any idea on how to solve the issue?

This is controller code :

```
    [HttpGet("{pubdate}")]
     public async Task<ActionResult<ToDoListDto>> GetTodListOfDates(DateTime pubdate)
          
        {
            var todo = await _toDoListRepository.GetIncomingToDoAsync(pubdate);
            if (todo == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(_mapper.Map<ToDoListDto>(todo));
        }
    

[HttpGet("{id}")]        
    public async Task<ActionResult<ToDoListDto>> GetTodList(int id)           
    {
        var todo = await _toDoListRepository.GetSpecificTodoAsync(id);
        if (todo == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(_mapper.Map<ToDoListDto>(todo));
    }
```

My Repository code:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ToDoList>> GetIncomingToDoAsync(DateTime dateTime)
            {
                return await _context.ToDoLists.Where(c => c.StartDate == dateTime).ToListAsync();
            }

public async Task<ToDoList?> GetSpecificTodoAsync(int taskId)
        {
            return await _context.ToDoLists.Where(c => c.Id == taskId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

My model for a todo:

```
public class ToDoListDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
     }
```

Comment: GetIncomingToDoAsync is probably returning an empty list. I don't think it will ever return null.

Comment: Could you please share your `_mapper.Map<ToDoListDto>(todo)` details and the format of `pubdate` and how the format existing in database. That would important to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping started by the datetime endpoint is trying to map an `IEnumerable<ToDoListDto>` while your integer endpoint is mapping a single `ToDoListDto`.

If you want to map each item in the collection individually (which is what the integer ID endpoint is doing), change the mapping in the datetime endpoint to the following:

```
return Ok(todo.Select(item => _mapper.Map<ToDoListDto>(item));
```

or, if you want to map the entire collection you have to be explicit and specify the type as `IEnumerable<ToDoListDto>`:

```
return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ToDoListDto>>(todo));
```